# Can`t import XML file in phpMyAdmin

Tags: xml, phpmyadmin

I`m currently trying to import xml format file of folowing structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<XMLBIBLE biblename="Ukrainian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
-<BIBLEBOOK bname="Name here" bnumber="1">
-<CHAPTER cnumber="1">
<VERS vnumber="1">Text here </VERS>
</CHAPTER>
-<CHAPTER cnumber="2">
<VERS vnumber="1">Text here</VERS>
and so on...
```

to the table I`ve created in OpenServer distributive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9eqD.png)

When I am trying to import my XML file via import button in php admin console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvFen.png)
I get such response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyxyT.png)

Instead I need these values im xml files to fill created fields.
Is anything I`m doing wrong. Will be appreciable to help me handle with it!

Comment: Xml file is not valid.  Use an online checker to find errors in the file.

Comment: Already did it, https://codebeautify.org/ says that xml file is valid

Comment: The last link above says that it is not. Maybe you are opening the wrong file.

Comment: I think you are missing tags like items and item.  See : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-load-xml-data-into-mysql-using-php/?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Recently did it. All validators saying that file is OK but I`m trying again and fail again. File is correct.

Comment: I would take small pieces of the xml file and try to isolate why the importer is failing.  It is probably a library issue with the upload.

Comment: @jdweng Probably issue in current program which i use as a remote server (OpenServer)

Comment: I can't get to following website because it is blocked.  It may help: https://docs.teamdrive.net/RegServer/3.0.018.6/html/common/Registration_Server_Configuration.html?force_isolation=true